# Python: Is is possible to use ARMA on a data set that is time dependent but not a time series itself?

Tags: python, statsmodels

Still new to python and the statsmodel package.

I have a dataset that is time dependent (my x values are attained sequentially but are not linear). Is it possible to use the ARMA model within statsmodel  without putting the index as a date?

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

x=[0,40,80,110...]
y=[1, 0.929487933, 0.875069014, 0.841214593...]

dataframe=pd.DataFrame(y, index=[x])
arma_model = sm.tsa.ARMA(dataframe, (1,0)).fit()
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates
```

Is there anyway around this?
Thanks